# Doxygen PLANTUML_JAR_PATH and source code management

Tags: git, version-control, doxygen, plantuml

So, we are using `doxygen` (version 1.8.9.1) and `plantuml` for uml diagrams.

The file `Doxyfile` contains

```
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH = /home/malff/plantuml/plantuml.jar
```

Note how the path is specific to a user.

Checking in this file in source control management (git) breaks other developers, since their path to plantuml.jar is different.

I beleive this is a bug in doxygen itself, reported as
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=753629

In the mean time, is there a known work around for using doxygen with plantuml in a distributed team ?

Comment: In case anyone else encounters the issue I had... my PLANTUML_JAR_PATH was set to the directory where `plantuml.jar` could be found and that worked fine when I ran doxygen via the command line. However when run from an Azure DevOps self-hosted agent it kept failing. I had to set PLANTUML_JAR_PATH to include plantuml.jar itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an environment variable, e.g. `PLANTUML_INSTALL_DIR` and then use

```
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH = $(PLANTUML_INSTALL_DIR)/plantuml.jar
```

in Doxygen's configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. Of course it works. I was not aware that the configuration file even -- supported -- environment variables ...